# Android:How to make sure that Camera is released propelry, when I am using AsyncTask to open it?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using `AsyncTask` to open camera in background thread. It works fine but at times(10 % chance) it will not release the camera and I will have blank preview screen if I open my app again and native camera shouts at me saying you haven't released camera resource.

Below is my `AsyncTask` code.

```
private class AsyncCamera extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Camera> {
    int _id = 0;

    public AsyncCamera(int id) {
        _id = id;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        releaseCameraAndPreview();
    }


    protected Camera doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Camera camera;
        camera = getCamera(_id);
        return camera;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Camera camera) {
        mCamera = camera;
        setCamera(camera);
        safeToTakePicture = true;
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

And `releaseCameraAndPreview()` method

```
private void releaseCameraAndPreview() {
    setCamera(null);//to stop preview and clear frame layout
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

here `getCamera()` method

```
private Camera getCamera(int id) {
    try {
        releaseCameraAndPreview();
        mCamera = Camera.open(id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mCamera;
}
```

And last `setCamera()` method.

```
public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    if (camera == null) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();

        }
        return;
    } else {
        //set parameters.clear frame layout and add view to it and start preview
        mCamera = camera;
        params = mCamera.getParameters();

        setPictureAndPreviewSize();
        if (mCamera != null) {

            mPreview = new Preview(getApplicationContext(), mCamera);
            mPreviewLayout.removeAllViews();
            mPreviewLayout.addView(mPreview);
        }
    }

}
```

`onPause()` method

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mPreview);
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
 }
```

I can produce the same error by pressing lock screen button while my app is open.

Comment: do you have the same problem if you open it from the UI thread?

Comment: @rupps no. If I open camera on UI thread it works fine. But we should not be doing it in main thread as it may take some time

Comment: yeah I guess, but some complex objects dont work well when created/initialized from a background thread, for example if they create a Handler and assume it will be created within the UI thread. Try to call Looper.prepare() in doInBackground to see if this is the case. And btw, I think opening the camera doesnt block even though it takes some time for the preview image to appear!